# Передача большого количества текста контроллеру mvc4

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

Всем здрасте преподаватель попросил написать контроллер который сможет принять большое количество текста, предупредил что устроит стресс-тесты, а именно передаст туда целую статью. Пробовал передавать большие тексты по стандартной маршрутизации `({controller}/{action}/{text})`, но ловил `HTTP Error 400`. В представлении только элемент textarea и кнопка "Отправить". Есть ли способы решения моей проблемы?

```
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Home
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult FirstTask(string text)
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

представление:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <a href="@Url.Action("FirstTask","Home")/Не следует, однако забывать, что постоянное информационно-пропагандистское обеспечение нашей деятельности требуют от нас анализа направлений прогрессивного развития. Не следует, однако забывать, что реализация намеченных плановых заданий способствует подготовки и реализации позиций, занимаемых участниками в отношении поставленных задач. Идейные соображения высшего порядка, а также постоянное информационно-пропагандистское обеспечение нашей деятельности играет важную роль в формировании дальнейших направлений развития.">Отправить</a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

P.S. Забыл упомянуть, я не использую форму т.к. преподаватель попросил реализовать это всё без форм, я написал через атрибут `<a>`, чтобы была ясна сущность моей проблемы.

Comment: Надеюсь неиспользование форм не подразумевает неиспользование аякса?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Отправка **POST** запроса без использования формы:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        @* без использования форм: *@
        <textarea id="text" name="text" rows="5"></textarea>
        <span id="btn" style="cursor:pointer;">Отправить</span>
    </div>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#btn').on('click', function(){
        $.ajax({
           url:'@Url.Action("FirstTask","Home")',
           type: 'POST',
           data: {text: $('#text').val()}
        }).success(function(result){
           // действия при удачной отправке
        }).error(function(err){
           console.log(err);
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы пытаетесь передать текст через ссылку, по нажатию которой отправляется запрос Get, а метод, принимающий данные, у вас имеет атрибут HttpPost. Может стоит убрать его. 
А в самой ссылке указать параметр text:

```
<a href='@Url.Action("FirstTask","Home")?text=далее идет текст'>Отправить</a>
```

А вообще лучше текст оформить как переменную и использовать одну из перегрузок метода Url.Action, чтобы передать в него параметр text и его значение

Comment: К сожалению не получится, т.к. ссылки получатся одинакого длинные. Исполдьзовать URL я не смогу т.к. требуется отправлять разный текст